# C++ Template - No Appropriate Default Constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, polymorphism

My End goal is to create a map of strings to functions allowing any of my components to be added to an object with a given string.
I'm assigning components by telling each component which object it belongs to and can effect.

Template Declaration:

```
template<typename T> BaseComponent * createInstance(Object* object) {return new T;}
```

ObjectManager Constructor:

```
   ObjectManager::ObjectManager()
{
    componentMap["ReadComponent"]  = &createInstance<ReadComponent>;
    componentMap["WriteComponent"] = &createInstance<WriteComponent>;
}
```

Component Addition:

```
    bool ObjectManager::Addcomponents(string ComponentType, int objectNumber)
{
    if (ComponentMap.find(componentType) != ComponentMap.end())
    {
        Objects.at(objectNumber)->Components.push_back(ComponentMap["ReadComponent"](&Objects.at(objectNumber)->object));
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

While for most of the file this works fine , it flags up on line 3 (My template declaration) that there is "no appropriate default constructor available" for either component type.

Below are my component constructors:

```
public:
    Readcomponent(Object* owner) : Basecomponent(owner)
    {
        this->Type = "Read";
    };


public:
    Writecomponent(Object* owner) : Basecomponent(owner)
        {
            this->Type = "Write";
            this->WriteText = "Writecomponent Online";
        };
```

I know I'm probably doing something stupid and basic, but can't for the life of me see where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Please turn this it into a complete, compilable, copy-n-paste'able example. Otherwise, it's very hard to help...

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to use `createInstance(Object* object) {return new T(object);}` to call the constructors with the `owner` argument?

Comment: Cheers LutzL, i thought it'd be something simple like that. That's got me all working and good to go. Shame you didn't write as an answer.

Comment: what's wrong with `std::map`